# iBeacon: Get RSSI wit coreBluetooth

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

Is it possible to get the RSSI value of a beacon only with coreBluetooth?

I have implemented the following code:

```
let manager = CLLocationManager()
var peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager()
var advertisedData:NSDictionary = NSDictionary()

//test if there is a working bluetooth connection
func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager!) {
    switch peripheral.state {
    case CBPeripheralManagerState.PoweredOn:
        self.peripheralManager.startAdvertising(self.advertisedData as [NSObject : AnyObject])

        println("success")
    default: println("default")
    }
}
```

Now i can test, if bluetooth is activated or not. But how can i get the RSSI value of the beacons? Is the possible only with CoreLocation?

Comment: You cannot discover an iBeacon through Core Bluetooth.  If your beacon advertises additional BLE services then you will be able to discover the peripheral and read the RSSI as per @Larme's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CLBeacon` has a property `rssi`, more info in [Apple's Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLBeacon_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLBeacon/rssi).

`CBPeripheral` has a `RSSI` property, which is deprecated in iOS8, Apple recommends to use [`readRSSI`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheral_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBPeripheral/readRSSI) instead.

Since normally, you should read your iBeacons values through `CLBeacon` (CoreLocation.framework), i'd recommend to use `rssi`. If you control your iBeacon through Bluetooth Low-Energy (CoreBluetooth.framework), use `readRSSI`.

Comment: With which method i can create a region for my Beacons or initiate the CBPeripheral for the beacons?